# One function that can use dynamic function swapping

Tags: c++

This might sound a little convoluted, but here we go.

So, I have the following code:

```
  void Utility::validateRangeAndModify(Pet pet, int checkint, 
                                       int numbertovalidate, 
                                       bool greaterorless)
{
    if (greaterorless) {
        if (numbertovalidate < checkint)
            pet.getAttributes()->setPetHunger(0);
    } else
        if (numbertovalidate > checkint)
            pet.getAttributes()->func(100);
}
```

Firstly, This code is designed to validate a single integer. That part is easy.

Then, what I want it to do is carry out **a** function depending on if the integer meets the condition or not. In this case, `setPetHunger()` is being set to either 0 or 100. The issue is, I have `setPetHealth()`, and `setPetEnergy()` too.

The **function** I want it to perform is the thing that I want to change.

For instance. **This code will only work for my pets Hunger**. *It won't work* for it's Health, Happiness, or any of it's other variables. and I have a ton of other variables.

I'm wondering if there is any way to achieve something like this:

```
 void Utility::validateRangeAndModify(Pet pet, 
                                     int checkint, 
                                     int numbertovalidate, 
                                     bool greaterorless, 
                                     string functiontouse)
{

    if (greaterorless) {
        if (numbertovalidate < checkint)
            pet.getAttributes()->setPetHunger(0);
    } else
        if (numbertovalidate > checkint)
            pet.getAttributes()->FUNCTION_TO_USE(100);
}
```

I could use something like reflection for this in C#. However,  I don't know an alternative function in c++

Comment: Look into pointers to member functions

Comment: Is there a reason why function pointers won't work?

Comment: @LukePark The hidden `this` parameter.

Comment: Pushing up against duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610046/stdfunction-and-stdbind-what-are-they-when-they-should-be-used

Comment: @user4581301 I think you misunderstood.  See the answer posted.

Comment: You wanted any reason. The most common reason it won't work is someone tries to use a method. It will be very hard to call one of `pet`'s methods as a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by passing the correct member function pointer as parameter to `Utility::validateRangeAndModify` as below:

```
void
Utility::validateRangeAndModify(Pet &pet, int checkint, int numbertovalidate, 
                                bool greaterorless, void(Attrib::*memfun)(int)) {
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  if(greaterorless) {
    if(numbertovalidate < checkint) (pet.getAttributes()->*memfun)(0);
  } else {
    if(numbertovalidate < checkint) (pet.getAttributes()->*memfun)(100);
  }
}
```

And then call it as (if `Utility::validateRangeAndModify` is not `static` use `obj.validateRangeAndModify`):

```
Utility::validateRangeAndModify(p, 10, 9, false, &Attrib::setPetHunger);
Utility::validateRangeAndModify(p, 10, 9, false, &Attrib::setPetThirst);
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f680a25a297a9b9)

Comment: getting an error: 'expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type.'

Comment: @MikeFredrik check the live demo and adjust accordingly. If you do it correctly should work.

Comment: Ah. I had a mistake. Works now. Thanks for the help bud, I appreciate it.

Comment: How would I acheive this?

`if (numbertovalidate < checkint) pet.getAttributes()->*setmemfun(pet.getAttributes()->*getmemfun + 1);`

Comment: @MikeFredrik You can pass two function pointers: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09a92d3b441e1da2

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function pointer:

```
  void Utility::validateRangeAndModify(Pet pet, int checkint, 
                                       int numbertovalidate, 
                                       bool greaterorless,
                                       void (*func)(int, attribs &))
{
    if (greaterorless) {
        if (numbertovalidate < checkint)
            pet.getAttributes()->setPetHunger(0);
    } else
        if (numbertovalidate > checkint)
            func(100, pet.getAttribs());
}
```

You and the client will agree on the prototype of the function that you will pass; in this case, the prototype will be `void func(int, attribs &);`

The client can write code like this:

```
void happiness(int level, attribs &a)
{
    // some code here
}
Utility::validateRangeAndModify(..., happiness);
```

Now `happiness` willl be called by your `validateRangeAndModify` function.

NOTE: `happiness` is a free function. If it is a member function, mark it as `static`: then there won't be the extra `this` argument.

Comment: This won't work. A pointer to member function is not the same as a pointer to a function

Comment: why would this not work? `happiness` is not part of any class, so it does not have the extra `this` argument. @Kevin

Comment: You aren't calling the `func` parameter but you're trying to call a `func` member function on `pet.getAttributes()`

Comment: A pointer to member function is used like this: `void (Object::*func)(int) = ...; (obj.*func)(123);`. You can also use `std::bind` to turn a member function into something that acts as a regular function to avoid the strange syntax.

Comment: Getting " Class 'Attributes' has no member 'func' "

Comment: See my comments. You could also have that `happiness` function take the attributes as a parameter and avoid the whole member function business entirely.

Comment: I edited my answer to show how you would pass a reference to a structure that would contain the attributes @MikeFredrik

Comment: `pet.getAttributes()->func(100)` tries to call a member function called `func` on the attributes. It has nothing to do with the parameter passed in. If you want to call a variable member function on an object use a pointer to member function (google it) or a regular function that takes the object as a parameter and calls the member function inside it (see stackptr's edit)

Comment: Tries to call func on the attributes, yeah. Got that part.

Nothing to do with the parameter passed in? what parameter?

Then I lost you.

I only learnt pointers last week, please go a little slower when explaining

Comment: 'initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue'

Answer (score 0):

To keep this simple, I'm providing a really trivial program that uses [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), and [std::placeholders](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders) to allow calls to a bound method. This keeps the correct `this` with the method and generally prevents nastiness.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

// bait class to catch bound function calls. Replace this with pet for OP's example
class TwoMethods
{
public:
    void method1(int val)
    {
        std::cout << "Method 1 received " << val << std::endl;
    }

    void method2(int val)
    {
        std::cout << "Method 2 received " << val << std::endl;
    }

};

// utility function that will operate on a bound function
void utilityfunction(std::function<void(int)> func)
{
    // calls passed function. Quietly handles bound this parameter and replaces 
    // placeholder with 42
    func(42);
}
int main()
{
    TwoMethods obj;

    // call utility function with appropriate object and method
    // the std::placeholders::_1 lets the compiler know there is another parameter that 
    // will be supplied later
    utilityfunction(std::bind(&TwoMethods::method1, obj, std::placeholders::_1));
    utilityfunction(std::bind(&TwoMethods::method2, obj, std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

In OP's case:

```
void Utility::validateRangeAndModify(int checkint, 
                                     int numbertovalidate, 
                                     bool greaterorless,
                                     std::function<void(int)> func)
{
    switch (greaterorless)
    {
        case 0: 
            {
                if (numbertovalidate < checkint) 
                { 
                    func(0); 
                }  
            } 
            break;
        case 1: 
            {
                if (numbertovalidate > checkint) 
                {
                    func(100); 
                } 
                break; 
            } 
    }
}
```

And called something like:

```
validateRangeAndModify(42, 666, false,
                       std::bind(&Attributes::setPetHunger,  
                                 pet.getAttributes(), 
                                 std::placeholders::_1))
```

Comment: 'Attributes has no member func'

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to. `func` already knows everything it needs to. The attributes were programmed in with the call to std::bind. There is no need for `pet.getAttributes()->func(0);`. You just call `func(0);`