# c++ is it possible to to point to a function with its variables defined

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I remember vaguely that python allowed something like

```
def foo( x ):
    ....

f = foo( 5 )
```

Is something like that possible in c++ so that if I have a member function

```
class C {

    void foo( int x ) { ... }

so that I can define a pointer or variable that would effectively point at foo( 5 )
```

The reason why I want to do this is because I have many listeners that I need to subscribe to a callback and keep information who gets called

```
class C {
     map<int, ptrSender> m_sender;

    void subscribe() {
        for (const auto& p : m_sender) {
            p .second->register( Callback( this, &C::onCall ) )
        }
```

My problem is that the onCall does not return which sender called back, but I would need this information. So, instead of doing something like this

```
    void subscribe() {
         m_sender[0]->register( Callback( this, onCall_0 ) );
         m_sender[1]->register( Callback( this, onCall_1 ) );
         ....

   void onCall( int sender_id ) { ... }
   void onCall_0() { onCall( 0 ); }
   void onCall_1() { onCall( 1 ); }
   ....
```

I was hoping I could pass something into register that would return a call with a preset argument. Is this possible?

EDIT: I am trying to use a lambda function, but I am running into the following problems

```
auto setCall= [this]( int v ) { &C::onCall( v ); }
```

gives the compile error

```
lvalue required as unary&opeand
```

This

```
auto setCall= [this]( int v ) { C::onCall( v ); }
.... 
p.second->register( Callback( this, &setCall( p.first) ) );   /// <__ error now here
```

complains again, now in the second line

```
lvalue required as unary&operand
```

and this

```
auto setCall= [this]( int v ) { C::onCall( v ); }
.... 
p.second->register( Callback( this, setCall( p.first) ) );   /// <__ error now here
```

complains about invalid use of void expression, but I assume I have to pass in a reference to make the register function happy

Callback seems to be defined as

```
#  define CallBack(obj,func) ProfiledBasicCallBack(obj,fastdelegate::FastDelegate0<void>(obj,func),#func)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

Comment: Looks like you want to use bind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610046/stdfunction-and-stdbind-what-are-they-when-they-should-be-used

Comment: That bind looks promising, let me try that

Comment: If you can prefer a lambda over bind.

Comment: What is the parameter types of your `register` function? The second parameter specifically.

Comment: I edited the text. actually there is a callback function passed into teh register function. I dont understand what creature that is, though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). Example usage: http://ideone.com/akoWbA.

```
void foo( int x ) { cout << x << endl; }
auto x = std::bind(foo, 5);
x();
```

However, with modern C++, you should use a lambda. Like so:

```
void foo( int x ) { cout << x << endl; }
auto x = []() { foo(5); };
x();
```

Note that this foo function is outside of the class C in this example. If you wish to contain it inside, then with std::bind you need to pass the instance of the object you wish to call on, e.g.

```
C c;
auto x = std::bind(&C::foo, &c, 5);
x();
```

or with lambdas:

```
C c;
auto x = [&c]() { c.foo(5); };
x();
```

Comment: @smac89 Thanks, my bad.

Comment: if you have std::bind available, you will have lambdas. They appeared in the same standard release. In c++11 there were a few use cases for bind, but it was mostly already an anachronism. As of c++14, there is no case in which bind is a better tool than a lambda. Use lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [std::bind()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). It takes one callable object, and gives you another callable object with predefined values for its parameter, and maybe some optional parameters forwarded to it.

A word of warning: this is a fairly steep learning curve. You need to understand templates.

Comment: I would never recommend std::bind over a lambda function. It's far more difficult to understand, and with `[&](){}` you have a much easier control what you need to copy, and what you can simply reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bind a parameter value to a compile-time constant argument (like `5` in your example), then the problem can be solved by introducing a simple wrapper function that will call your function while passing the desired constant values as corresponding arguments.

But when the argument is a run-time value, then the answer is no: it is generally not possible to create a credible implementation of such *function pointer* binding in C++ (unless you are using some compiler-specific extension).

However, in C++ you have a variety of alternative tools at your disposal. You can create a *function object* that will mimic the functionality you desire. Such function object can be created by using `std::bind`, by using lambda-expressions, or even implemented manually.

The resultant *function object* will be "callable" and will behave similarly to function pointer at superficial level, but nevertheless it won't be a *function pointer*, won't be convertible to a *function pointer* and won't be accepted where a genuine *function pointer* is required. In other words, if your `register` method is declared to expect a function pointer as its second argument, then there's nothing you can do here. Neither `std::bind`, nor lambdas, nor anything else in the language will help you to achieve this kind of parameter binding.

For this reason it is generally a good idea to steer clear of function pointers in such designs and implement such functionality in terms of generic callable objects. The simplest thing to use might be `std::function` objects in place of raw function pointers.