# Using boost:bind to bind a std::function

Tags: c++, function, boost, boost-bind

I have a problem using boost::bind with a function stored into std::function.

This is related to boost::asio: I am building a basic UDP server.
So, first lets see some code that compiles fine **without** std::function (whole code [on Coliru here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2503ccdbd1e6b98e), uncomment the define to see the problem):

Here only the relevant part:

```
class udp_server
{
        void start_receive()
        {
            _socket.async_receive_from(
                boost::asio::buffer( _buffer ),
                _remote_endpoint,
                boost::bind(
                    &udp_server::_rx_handler,
                    this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
                    42
                )
            );
        }

        void _rx_handler( const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t bytes_rx, int );
};
```

As you can see, I am passing the handler `_rx_handler` (aka "callback") to the boost::asio function, so that when something gets received, the function will be called.
As I need a third argument and the "asio" function requires a specific function signature, I am using boost::bind. So far so good.

**Now**, I want to inherit this class into another one, where I can define some more specific things to do upon receiving data.
So I replace in base class the handler with a std::function, with same signature:

```
std::function< void( const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t bytes_rx, int )> _rx_handler;
```

or, more conveniently, using a typedef;

```
typedef std::function< void( const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t bytes_rx, int ) > CALLBACK_T;
...
CALLBACK_T _rx_handler;
```

That way (I thought), I can add a member function to assign any member function from an inherited class:

```
void assignCallback( CALLBACK_T f )
{
    _rx_handler = f;
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not compile.
GCC 5.4.1 says:

> /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:69:37: error: ‘std::function udp_server::*’ is not a class, struct, or union type

But when I check [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), I read that it **is** a class template...

After looking at this page, I also tried to access the pointer on function with `target()`:

```
boost::bind(
    &udp_server::_rx_handler.target(),
    this,
    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
    42
)
```

but this does not compile either:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘std::function::target()’
>         udp_server::_rx_handler.target(),

**Question**: What is wrong here? I thought a "real" function and std::function were interchangeable?
How can I make this work?

*Addendum: I have the feeling that this is possibly related to my lack of knowledge on how the whole binding thing works, so thanks for any insights!*

Possibly related: [std::function and std::bind: what are they & when they should be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610046/)

Comment: Your `std::function` is not a member function anymore, so you don't want the `this` parameter when calling `boost::bind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binding should be modified as follow:

```
void start_receive()
{
    _socket.async_receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer( _buffer ),
        _remote_endpoint,
        boost::bind(
            udp_server::_rx_handler,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
            42
        )
    );
}
```

You change `_rx_handler` from `void (udp_server::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t bytes_rx, int);` to `std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t bytes_rx, int)>`

So you no longer have to bind to an instance to `udp_server`.

Comment: What got me wrong is that technically speaking `_rx_handler` is **still** a class member. Thanks !