# Compiler unable to deduce template arguments for variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Suppose I want to do [partial function application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6610165/1437100) to make a wide range of functions conform to a single signature.

For example, I could want to go from a double-parameter function to a single-parameter function as follows:

```cpp
std::function<int(int, int)> doubleFoo = [](int i, int j) { return i + j; };
// Turn the function into a single-parameter function, using j = 5
std::function<int(int)> singleFoo = toSingleFoo(doubleFoo, 5);
```

As I want `toSingleFoo` to handle any single- or multi-argument function of which the first argument is an `int`, I've defined it as a variadic template function:

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
std::function<int(int i)> toSingleFoo(std::function<int(int, Args&&...)> multiFoo, Args&&... args)
{
    auto singleFoo = [args](int i) { multiFoo(i, std::forward<Args>(args)...) };
    return singleFoo;
}
```

However, that gives the following compiler errors (using Visual Studio 2017, version 15.7.6):

```
error C2672: 'toSingleFoo': no matching overloaded function found
error C2784: 'std::function<int (int)> toSingleFoo(std::function<int(int,Args &&...)>,Args &&...)':
              could not deduce template argument for 'std::function<int(int,Args &&...)>' 
              from 'std::function<int (int,int)>'
```

Why is the compiler unable to deduce template arguments, despite an `int` being passed as second argument in the example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start off, you need to capture `multiFoo`, as well as capture the variadic `args...`.

The issue with the deduction seems to be in the `std::function` argument. If you only allow it to deduce `Args...` from the second argument, deduction proceeds as expected.

To hide the deduction of the first argument, just put it in an identity template

```
template<typename T>
struct I { using type = T; };
```

Then you can define the function as

```
template <typename... Args>
std::function<int(int)> toSingleFoo(
                          typename I<std::function<int(int, Args&&...)>>::type multiFoo, 
                          Args&&... args)
{
    return [multiFoo, &args...] (int i) {
        return multiFoo(i, std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
    };
}
```

and then use it

```
int main() {
    std::function<int(int, int)> doubleFoo = [](int i, int j) { return i + j; };
    // Turn the function in a single-parameter function, using j = 5
    std::function<int(int)> singleFoo1 = toSingleFoo(doubleFoo, 5);

    std::cout << singleFoo1(3); // prints 8

    std::function<int(int, int, int)> tripleFoo = [](int i, int j, int k) { return i * j * k; };
    // Turn the function in a single-parameter function, using j = 2, k = 3
    std::function<int(int)> singleFoo2 = toSingleFoo(tripleFoo, 2, 3);

    std::cout << singleFoo2(4); // prints 24
}
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! How did you come up with the identity template solution? Is that a known pattern?

Comment: Absolutely, in fact it's [coming](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) in c++20

Comment: Ah, `type_identity can be used to establish non-deduced contexts in template argument deduction`. Useful note :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's its entire purpose :)

Comment: Further reading: section '_Non-deduced contexts_' of ['Template argument deduction' at cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)